# How to setup a model twitter style using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

Code from rails best practices

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tweet = current_user.tweets.limit(10)
    @trending = Topic.trending(5)
  end

  def retweet
    tweet = tweet.find(params[id])
    flash[:notice] = tweet.retweet_by(current_user)
    redirect_to tweet
  end
end

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :recent.order('createted_at DESC')
  # Overwrite the default scope
  #@tweets = current_user.tweets.unscoped.order(:status).limit(10)

  def retweet_by(retweeter)
    if self.user == retweeter
      "Sorry, you can't retweet you own tweet"
    elsif self.retweets.where(user_id: retweeter.id).present?
      "You already retweeted!"
    else
      s = tweet.new
      s.status = "RS #{tweet.user.name}: #{tweet.status}"
      s.original_tweet = tweet
      s.user = current_user
      s.save
      "Succesfully retweeted"
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to add reshare to my blog app

from the above code I am guessing the model should be:

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tweets do |t|
      t.string  :status
      t.integer :original_tweet
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :Tweets, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
 end
```

and this line

```
self.retweets.where(user_id: retweeter.id).present?
```

give me the idea that there should be a separate model retweet with user_id and tweet_id

how can I set up view for this code with retweet link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to recreate Twitter functionality, you'd have to keep your "data" models separate (`user` and `tweet`):

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tweets
end


#app/models/tweet.rb
Class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
    has_many :retweets, class_name: "Tweet", foreign_key: "retweet_id"
end
```

---

**Schema**

```
users
id | info | about | user | created_at | updated_at

tweets
#retweet_id for retweets
id | user_id | retweet_id | status | created_at | updated_at
```

---

This would allow you to call things like:

```
@user.tweets.each do |tweet|
    tweet.status
    tweet.created_at
end
```

or

```
@tweet.author
```

---

**Retweet**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tweets do
    member do
        post :retweet
    end
end

#app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb
def retweet
    @retweet = Tweet.new(retweet_params)
    @retweet.save
end

private

def retweet_params
    params.require(:retweet).permit(:retweet_id, :status).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end

#app/views/tweets/show.html.erb
<%= link_to tweet_retweet_path(tweet.id), method: :post %>
```

Comment: what about the view, how do I create the retweet link

Comment: Hey buddy, was going to write an update for you - but had to finish some work I was sorting out! I have provided an update